# Java - How do I pass the return type of a method as parameter?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a small game with a TUI. The TUI should have a `get()` method that should take a `String question` and a return type as parameter, so you can use it to request an object.

For example, `get("What is your name?", String)` should return a `String` and `get("What color do you want?", Color)` should return a `Color`.

This is what I've come up with:

```
public interface View {

    public <T> T get(String question, Class<T> type) throws InputException;

}

public class TUI implements View {

    public Color get(String question, Class<Color> type) {
        // code
    }

    public String get(String question, Class<String> type) {
        // code
    }

}

Color color = Game.getView().get("What piece do you want to place?", Color.class);
```

Unfortunately, the methods in `TUI` are not accepted as implementations of public `<T> T get(String question, Class<T> type) throws InputException;`. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: thats a reasonable code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keeping it type safe by splitting the functions would seem more appropriate:

```
Color color = Game.getView().getColor("What piece do you want to place?");
String string = Game.getView().getString("What piece do you want to place?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make two classes AskColor and AskString that implements View, with method respectively

```
  public Color get(String question, Class<Color> type) {
    // code
}

public String get(String question, Class<String> type) {
    // code
}
```

and the interface View with method

```
public T get(String question, Class<T> type) throws InputException;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `TUI` class is not valid because under type erasure both `get` methods have the same arguments.

You might want to do this:

```
public interface View<T> {
    T get(String question, Class<T> type) throws InputException;
}

public class ColorTUI implements View<Color> {
    public Color get(String question, Class<Color> type) {
        // code
    }
}

public class StringTUI implements View<String> {
    public String get(String question, Class<String> type) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding multiple classes will only make things more complicated. I'm trying to make my code more simple. Isn't there any way to write multiple get methods in TUI using different return types, without adding all methods to the View interface?

Comment: No, that is not possible in Java. This would not even work without the interface (i.e. if you have only the TUI class), because the methods would have the same call signature due to type erasure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to Template Method Design Pattern.

```
public interface TypeTemplate {
    public Object get(String question);
}
public class ColorTemplate implements TypeTemplate {
    @Override public Color get(String question) { /*code for color*/ }
}
public class StringTemplate implements TypeTemplate {
    @Override public String get() { /*code for string*/ }
}

public class TUI {
    public Color get(String question, ColorTemplate templ) {
        return templ.get(String question)
    }
    public String get(String question, StringTemplate templ) {
        return templ.get(String question);
    }
}



public static void main(String args[]) {
    TUI tui = new TUI();
    String string = tui.get("What is your name?", new StringTemplate());
    Color color = tui.get("What color do you want?", new ColorTemplate());
}
```

You can of course replace `Object` type in `TypeTemplate` with something less generic. You can also make `TypeTemplate` one abstract class; this way if all (or some) of your `get()` methods will have to share some code you can add methods in this class and call from the subclasses. e.g.

```
public abstract class TypeTemplate {
    public abstract Object get(String question);
    protected void init() {/*some initialization code*/} 
    protected void cleanup(){/*some more code*/}
}
public class ColorTemplate implements TypeTemplate {
    @Override
    public Color get(String question) {
        init();
        /*code for color*/
        cleanup(); 
    }
}
public class StringTemplate implements TypeTemplate {
    @Override
    public String get() {
        init();
        /*code for string*/
        cleanup(); 
    }
}
```